# Could I list the conference that I didn't attend in the PhD application system even I got my paper accepted?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, application

I am applying for a Ph.D. position in a university. Their system required me to fill in the conferences I attended.
 
I published my paper on one conference although I didn't attend it personally for some reasons. My advisor went on my behalf. However, if I denied that I had attended that conference, the system doesn't even allow me to upload my paper. I think the paper is an important proof of my research ability.
What should I do? Should I just pretend I attended it. I don't even think they will really check about this thing.

Comment: Can you specify a list of publications, too? Then this is where your paper should go, and then you shouldn't claim double credit if you didn't attend the conference.

Comment: Doesn't the application include a CV?  Just include the publication on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, **no**. If they ask you to specify a list of attended conferences, then a conference that you didn't attend doesn't belong in your answer, even if your paper was accepted. Claiming that you attended the conference  would be incorrect and could lead to problems if someone found out.

Normally, you should be able to get credit for your accepted conference paper in another category, where you're asked for a list of your peer-reviewed articles.

However, the form could be designed in a way which neglects the existence of peer-reviewed conference papers. For example, you might be asked for a list for your journal articles only, because the form designers were unaware of fields in which journal articles are not the only kind of peer-reviewed publications. In this case, you should seek contact to the admission committee and ask how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

My reading here is that Conferences Attended and Papers Published are not the same thing.

You could attend a conference purely to watch the other presentations, to make contacts or to participate in workshops. You can also attend non-academic conferences, or conferences held within your university.

Based on the way this has been listed, I would not included the paper in this section. However, hopefully there will be the opportunity to submit your list of Publications elsewhere.